# Access a Qlikview dashboard on an iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad, qlikview

I have a *Qlikview* dashboard that I need to present and I've created a site that loads the *Qlikview* server onto the browser and runs it from there.

I now need to create an iOS app that does this. But the requirement is that the dashboard shouldn't open on the browser. The server should be loaded and run from the app itself. Is there any way to do this?

PS, I'm completely new to iOS App development and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** While saving it as a shortcut and opening it in the browser would be simple, using [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.io/) is the best way to develop a smartphone app with HTML5/CSS/JavaScript. From the website:

> When using the Cordova APIs, an app can be built without any native
>   code (Java, Objective-C, etc) from the app developer. Instead, web
>   technologies are used, and they are hosted in the app itself locally
>   (generally not on a remote http server).

And to make things better, it's open source.

Comment: Oh! Thanks :)
That does help.

Comment: No problem. You can also find out more about Qlik's mobile products here: http://www.qlik.com/us/explore/products/mobile. Consider accepting this answer if it answered your question. Good luck!